# Change the content of a dialog box when onClick event occurs

Tags: android, dialog, android-alertdialog

In my application, I have created a dialog box to accept password. In the dialog a message, an EditText and two buttons (one +ve and one -ve) are present. When user clicks on the +ve button, I am checking whether the password entered in the EditText is valid or not. If not valid, I have to change the message of the dialog box prompting the user to re-enter the password again.

If the password is valid it works as per the expectation, but it is invalid, instead of updaing the message it simply closes the dialog.

I have already tried to solve it by overriding **onPrepareDialog()**, but it also doesn't work.

Here is my code:

```
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int viewId){
    AlertDialog dialog = null;
    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setMessage("Enter Password To Continue");
            final EditText passwordField = new EditText(getApplicationContext());
            builder.setView(passwordField);
            builder.setPositiveButton("SUBMIT", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    if(passwordField.getText().toString().equals("password")){
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MyFirstActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
                        finish();
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }else{
                            //Here I need to update the message
                        builder.setMessage("SORRY!!! Wrong Password Entered.\n Re-Enter Correct Password Again ");
                    }                       
                }
            });
            builder.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
            dialog =  builder.create();
    }
    return dialog;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there are 2 issues here.

1. If I recall correctly the default behavior of the PositiveButton on an AlertDialog will close the dialog. I think that is why yours is closing when the password is wrong. I think if you switch to

   ```
   builder.setNeutralButton(...);
   ```

   it will not close your dialog when pressed.
2. You are changing the message on the Builder instead of the Dialog itself. I don't think the Builder will dynamically change the way the Dialog looks once it has already been created and shown.

   ```
   dialog.setMessage("WRONG PASSWORD");
   ```

will change it for you I think. If not then you'll have to make a TextView and add it to your Dialog with `builder.setView(mTxt);` then you can call `setText();` on your reference and it will change the text on the screen.

I think a better solution than either might be a [Toast](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html) pop-up though. The user has just typed a password and pressed submit so I think they can be counted on to be looking at the screen. Many other applications that have logins pages use Toast message to tell the user if they got the password wrong, so I don't think you'll be confusing your users or anything, it is a common design patter.

**EDIT:**

AlertDialog class definitely does have a setMessage() method. [see the docs here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html#setMessage%28java.lang.CharSequence%29). It is near the bottom of the docs page so it won't scroll it to the top when you click the link correctly. But it is there, 3rd one down from the top for me. Between `setInverseBackgroundForced` and `setTitle`

**EDIT 2:**

I implemented something similar to what you are trying to do a while ago. I had to use my own Custom Listener object with the dialog buttons I think in order to get them to not hide the Dialog upon being pressed.

Here is how I create and show the dialog:

```
  AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(YourActivity.this);
  builder.setCancelable(false)
  .setMessage("Please Enter Something")

  .setPositiveButton("Enter", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
        //All of the fun happens inside the CustomListener now.
        //I had to move it to enable data validation.
        }
   });
   AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
   alertDialog.show();
   Button theButton = alertDialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
   theButton.setOnClickListener(new CustomListener(alertDialog));
```

Then I created an Inner class inside my Activity called CustomListener like this:

```
class CustomListener implements View.OnClickListener {
    private final Dialog dialog;
    public CustomListener(Dialog dialog) {
        this.dialog = dialog;
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {


        if(passwordField.getText().toString().equals("password")){
            //Password is correct.


        } else { //Password is incorrect.
            ((AlertDialog)dialog).setMessage("WRONG");
        }
    }
}
```

When you set the listener in this manner it will not close the Dialog automatically upon button press.

Comment: Tim, your first suggestion is completely wrong, as dialog has not setMessage() or similar method. I tried your 2nd suggestion, which changes the textview content, but it immediately closes the dialog. Do you have any idea to make the dialog visible even after clicking the natural button "SUBMIT".

Comment: But you are using AlertDialog, not Dialog. And AlertDialog does have setMessage(), see my edit for link to javadoc. Also I still think Toast is a better solution than either setMessage() or a TextView.

Comment: Tim my client is not ready to listen anything. So I have to achieve this with Dialog only. 2nd thing is, it changes the message with setMessage() but the dialog suddenly disappears. What to do for this?

Comment: I am not psychic, I had no way to know anything about your client. And in the code that you provided you are already using an AlertDialog... If you are not allowed to use AlertDialog then you are going to have to scrap almost everything that you posted in your question. Which means that you are trying to ask an entirely different question than the one that you've posted.

Comment: Tim I think I am failed to explain my words because of my poor English. My client is not allowing me to show the message using Toast. It says I have to solve it by updating the message of the AlertDialog only. But after trying your answer, I succeed in updating the message but my AlertDialog closes automatically.

Comment: Ah, I understand now. I went back to an application I wrote a while ago that did something similar to this. Looks like I had to use my own CustomListener object instead of the setPositive() / setNeutral() methods of the builder in order to get the Dialog to stay showing. See my new edit for details.

Comment: Tim your answer is working perfect. I found another answer, you can see that posted in answer.

Answer (score 1):

Though the answer provided by **Tim** is correct, but I still post my answer, to help some one who want some more alternative answers in future.

After a long search I solved this in another way by overriding **onShow()** method.

```
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int viewId){
    AlertDialog dialog;
    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

            builder.setMessage("Enter Password To Continue");
            final TextView message = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
            message.setText("Enter Password To Continue");
            builder.setView(message);

            final EditText passwordField = new EditText(getApplicationContext());
            builder.setView(passwordField);
            builder.setPositiveButton("SUBMIT", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        //Do Nothing
                                    }
            });
            builder.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
            dialog =  builder.create();
            dialog.setOnShowListener(new OnShowListener() {

                @Override
                public void onShow(final DialogInterface dialog) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Button b = ((AlertDialog) dialog).getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
                    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                                       if(passwordField.getText().toString().equals("password")){
                                Intent intent = new Intent(PuzzleHome.this, PuzzleMaker.class);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }else{
                                ((AlertDialog) dialog).setMessage("SORRY!!! Wrong Password Entered.\n Re-Enter Correct Password Again");
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
    }
    return dialog;
}
```